# Sending double data from Matlab to the Teensy 3.6 via the microUSB

Tags: teensy, serial-data, matlab

I've been hitting against a wall for over a week now.  My current project is to use a Teensy 3.6 to send data over an SPI bus to a chip which is effective going to be a signal generator.  I've made a GUI in Matlab to control this function generator in 'real-time' by sending over values such as frequency and amplitude.  For my initial case, I just want to output a sine wave.  to do this I am using the built in math function sin and just getting the amplitude and frequency from Matlab.  However, when I send over my data I'm getting nothing on the output, but when I hard program in the values, it works just fine.  From this I assume I am not sending the data over correctly OR not converting it correctly upon receiving it.

My order of operations are:

1. send my variable to the Teensy 3.6 using fwrite in Matlab

   ```
   serialID = serial('COM5','BaudRate',115200);                    
   fopen(serialID);                           
   val = 2.55;
   fwrite(serialID, val, 'double');
   ```
2. receiving the data on the Teensy 3.6 using Serial.read()

   ```
   byte temp[8];

   for (int c = 0; c<8; c++){
       temp[c] =Serial.read();
   }
   ```
3. converting my byte array to a double using a union

   ```
   double byteToDouble(byte DoubleInBytes[8]) {
       //Receives 8 bytes values and return them into a double value

       union {
          double   Out;                                                      
          byte   In[8];                                                      
       } U ;

       for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
           U.In[c] = DoubleInBytes[c];
       }

       return U.Out;
   }
   ```

I'm at a loss as to what I might be doing wrong.  I've tried to use the serial monitor to monitor variable states but I can't use that while Matlab is using the COM port.

Any helpful tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified byte-order? And read when there is data available, i.e. check Serial.available().

Comment: Yes, they are both little endian.  And yes, I used Serial.available to see if data is available.  I'm currently reading in the data and sending back some debugging text to Matlab to see where I am in the code.  When I hard code the numbers in I actually still read in data but don't use it to get into the if(Serial.available()) portion of the code.

Comment: You mean `if (Serial.available() >= 8)`.

Comment: I did write it wrong, but not >= 8 but rather if(Serial.available() > 0)  I just want to know something is ready to be pulled before starting.

Answer (score -1):

I got a bit more traction on this issue on the Arduino forums and was able to answer it over there.  I'm posting the link here to complete this post with a working answer.  Hope it helps!

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=598595.new#new

Thanks!